# Nested resource json rendering location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a small part(callback for jsonp) to my `/groups/1/clients.json` file. But I don't know which method in groups(or clients) formats that json file for me.

I've tried editting my clients#show and clients#index and also my groups#show and groups#index methods; to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you paste some of your code . your  question is not clear

Comment: Because it's not a code related question. I want to add something to my json render for the nested resource. But I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your url "/groups/1/clients", it call clients controller index method only because there are nested resources so groups is the parents of clients, so that means group 1's all clients show so it call index methods of clients. so put your json code inside clients controller's index methods

Comment: What would be the variable used in my index(it's empty now because I didn't need it yet). Just `@clients`?

Comment: yup you must use @clients variable in index method according rails convention.

Comment: find their all clients of perticuler groups eg. @clients = Group.find(params[:id]).clients

Comment: Using only `render :text => 123` in my index shows 123 on /clients.json/ but on /groups/1/clients.json I still see the clients json(without callback). So I'm assuming the index method of clients is not used.

Comment: then write below this line... <br> render json: @clients

Comment: Same deal. It just doesn't use the clients#index for some reason

Comment: Ugh, never mind. I diverted the route a long while back and forgot about it. Got it fixed in my custom method :D